# Build error with Swift public convenience initializers in frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, initialization

I have a question regarding swift convenience initializers. I have a project ComputerAlgebra. This is a Cocoa Framework (for iOS at the moment) and it contains this code:

```
public class CANumber{
    public convenience init(value:String){
    ...
    }
}
```

This builds fine.

Now, I use this framework in another project and want to use CANumber there. I now get an build error:

```
Duplicate declaration of method 'initWithValue'
```

When I click the message, it brings me to an intermediate file ComputerAlgebra-swift.h. There, it reads:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC15ComputerAlgebra8CANumber")
@interface CANumber : CABasicTerm
...
- (instancetype)initWithValue:(NSString *)value;
@end
```

Obviously, XCode generates a header (is this a bridging header?) with the wrong access level, resulting in two declarations of the initializer. When I replace '-' with '+' at the beginning of the line, the project compiles nicely. This happens only with public convenience initializers.

BTW: I am running Xcode 6.1.1

Since I use only swift and no Objective-C: Is there a way to either skip the generation of the *.h file or is there any other way to generate the "correct" code in the *.h file. It is quite cumbersome to manually replace all '-'.

Thanks for your help.

Ralf